# Defining a list in a Spring application context file

Tags: java, spring

Can you create a List in a Spring application-context.xml file without using the `<list>` element?

I have a bean whose constructor takes a `Collection` object and I want to pass the entire list through the "value" attribute.  The reason is that this value comes from a .properties file and you can't define a list in a .properties file.

I want to do something like this...is it possible?

MyClass.java:

```
public class MyClass{
  public MyClass(Collection<String> collection){ /* ... */ }
}
```

application-context.xml:

```
<bean name="myBean" class="com.company.MyClass">
  <constructor-arg value="${the.value}" />
</bean>
```

.properties file:

```
the.value=item1,item2,item3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<bean name="myBean" class="com.company.MyClass">
  <constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.springframework.util.StringUtils" factory-method="commaDelimitedListToSet">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${the.value}"/>
    </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Ah, nice. (Except for the "Ew!" factor; egads.)

Comment: You can't have whitespace surrounding the commas though, otherwise the whitespace will be part of the item.  I could use `delimitedListToStringArray` and define the delimitor as ", ", but that makes the space required, which isn't what I want.  But it's not that big a deal.  I updated my question to remove the spaces between the commas.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution for your problem is to pass a single string to your constructor and then parse the list inside the constructor using [`String.split()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but I don't want to have to create a separate constructor if I don't have to.

Comment: in your case unfortunately, I believe you have to do so.  You could always delegate the constructor logic to the actual constructor after parsing the string.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe so, but you could have a constructor that built the list from a string.

(Actually, not entirely sure I'm correct--you could probably play significant games with custom placeholder configurators, although whether or not you *should* is probably debatable :)

Comment: I could create a separate constructor that takes a String and parses it into a list, but I don't want to if I don't have to.

Comment: Another option that doesn't resort to treachery is to create a separate bean that *does*, and use that bean (ultimately a list) as the constructor argument. But when you keep non-property-like things in a property file, IMO, things get irritating. [Although this may help :)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599086/reading-a-list-from-a-java-properties-using-spring-properties-place-holder)

Comment: I'd rather create a new constructor than define more beans.

Answer (score 1):

This works. 
You can use SPEL.

In the bean config,

```
<property name="collection" value="#{{'item1','item2','item3'}}"/>
```