# spEL in Bean Definition File : How to get a value in an inline list?

Tags: spring, spring-el

Given an inline list from a properties file:

```
nameList=john,smith,junior
```

From the bean definition file, I want to always extract the first item in my list. In this case, I would extract 'john'.

Using Spring Framework 3.0.4.RELEASE, my bean property looks as follows:

```
<property name="mySingleName" value="${nameList}" />
```

This obviously gives me the whole list.

I attempted to use the following to get the first item in the name list, but was met with an error:

```
<property name="mySingleName" value="#{${nameList}[0]}" />
```

The error was:

> BeanExpressionException:Exception parsing failed: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression:'comma(,)'

I have looked in the Book "Spring In Action", and have looked at the Spring spEL Documentation on Springs website. I have also googled for a quite a bit. Unfortunately, most of the code examples are done in code and not on the spring definition files. Any assistance in this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you are reading a "nameList" property as a String ( not as a `java.util.List` ). You would need to convert it to a list first:

```
<bean id="listOfNames" class="org.springframework.util.StringUtils" factory-method="commaDelimitedListToSet">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${nameList}"/>
</bean>
```

and then you can apply SPeL to it:

```
<property name="mySingleName" value="#{listOfNames[0]}" />
```

similar problem / solution here: [Spring: Reading collections form property files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652475/defining-a-list-in-a-spring-application-context-file/7654770#7654770)

Comment: Would be nice to inline the use of StringUtils so you don't need the extra bean, don't you think?

Comment: I came to the same conclusion yesterday, but it still felt messy to me. I was hoping to see some other solution. I agree with iwein, it would be nice to see something like #{(LIST)listOfNames[0]}, where spEL would auto-cast an inline list and allow you to extract its contents. Thank you tolitius.