# How to inject all properties from Spring into a bean?

Tags: java, spring

I want to inject a map containing all the properties that spring knows of (which are inserted by a library) to a config class that I have through the spring xml. Is that possible?

```
<bean class="Config">
  <constructor-arg name="env">
    <map>
    //inject all properties?
    </map>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just inject the Spring Context?  Through the Context, you can look up any bean via its name.

**Edit:**

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599086/reading-a-list-from-a-java-properties-using-spring-properties-place-holder), you could also use the following:

```
<bean class="Config">
  <constructor-arg name="env">
    <util:properties location="${path.to.properties.file}"/>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Where your "env" constructor argument is a java.util.Properties object.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? Inject the context in the Config class? Then how do I get the properties? The main reason I am trying to do it this way is because the spring context is owned by a library that I use and I can add more beans to it but i can't really control how it's created.

Comment: Hmmm, first can you define what you mean by properties?

Comment: java.util.Properties -- basically a string/string map

Comment: Do you use this through Spring's PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to insert the properties into your spring context files?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't/can't as the library that I use overwrites the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. That's why I want to get access to the properties that it loaded.

Comment: You could probably do what this post suggests and load in the properties then into a Properties class:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599086/reading-a-list-from-a-java-properties-using-spring-properties-place-holder

Answer (score 1):

For later versions of Spring (including spring-boot) that support the injection of an [Environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) you can use this to access all properties loaded.

To answer this question inject a `AbstractEnvironment` so that you are able to call the getPropertySources() method that will allow you to see where the properties have been loaded from  (e.g. a file, OS variables, etc)

```
@Autowired
public Config(AbstractEnvironment environment)
{
    MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();

    // inspect propertySources to see all properties loaded by Spring
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not extend the library class that you use and instantiate your bean instead of the default library one?  Then you would be able to inspect all the values.

Otherwise, if you know the signature of the library, you can always use AOP to weave some code around the library and get access to the properties there.  A bit more complicated, but still gets you where you need to go.  You can definitely use [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/index.html) (which requires a little more config) or even [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/aop.html), depending how things are being accessed.

If you want/need more insight on this, let me know.