# How load set of properties and then access it using spring framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring web application. Let's say it is managing an animals zoo.
In my property file I am writing how much animals there are and for each animal its type and name as following :

```
animal.number = 2
animal.1.type= tall
animal.1.name= Simba
animal.2.type= small
animal.2.name= Pumba
```

Now i would like to use this property in my application using spring way. In my config.xml i could write something like following.

```
<bean id="animal" class="com.zoo.animalsManaging">
    <property name="animalNumber" value="${animal.number}" />
    <property name="animal1Name" value="${animal.1.name}" />
    <property name="animal1Type" value="${ animal.1.type}" />
    <property name="animal2Name" value="${animal.2.name}" />
    <property name="animal2Type" value="${ animal.2.type}" />
</bean>
```

The problem is that animalNumber will always change. I am wondering if there is a spring way to get the entire animal property and then access to sub property by let's say animal.1.type.

Comment: your bean is not properly designed . create animal object and use list<animal> in bean

Answer (score 2):

As guided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1599197/2182351) you can use the util:properties

Animal properties

```
animal.1.type= tall
animal.1.name= Simba
animal.2.type= small
animal.2.name= Pumba
animal.number= 2
```

application.xml configuration

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:animal.properties"/>

    <bean name="zoo" class="com.stack.Zoo" init-method="init">
      <property name="animalProperties">
         <!-- not sure if location has to be customizable here; set it directly if needed -->
        <util:properties location="${classpath:animal.properties}"/>
      </property>
      <property name="numberOfAnimals" value="${animal.number}" />
    </bean>
```

Zoo is class Hold list of animals from Properties.

```
public class Zoo {
    Properties animalProperties;
    private Integer numberOfAnimals;
    List<Animal> animals;

    public void init() {
        animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        if (numberOfAnimals > 0) {
            StringBuffer key = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfAnimals; i++) {
                key.setLength(0);
                key.append("animal.").append(i).append(".type");
                String type = this.animalProperties.getProperty(key.toString());
                key.setLength(0);
                key.append("animal.").append(i).append(".name");
                String name = this.animalProperties.getProperty(key.toString());
                animals.add(new Animal(name,type));
                System.out.println("Animals Added");
            }
        }


    }
// Setter and getter Methods
}
```

In Post Construct , we are reading the properties and creating the Animal Instances.

```
numberOfAnimals  value injected by Spring.
```